# Adding multiple ManyToManyField objects in one queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have a django model structure as follows:

```
class Slot(models.Model):
    timing = models.DateTimeField()

class SlotBooking(models.Model):
    slot = models.ManyToManyField(Slot)
    token = models.CharField()
```

When saving to `SlotBooking`, I want to know if it's possible to do the following if the input slots are an array of slot IDs, eg: `[1, 2, 3 , 6, 23]`:

```
slot_booking = SlotBooking(slot=[array_of_slots], token=value)
slot_booking.save()
```

If not, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot update related object https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update

try create bulk relations using through model, something like this (I've not tested):

```
from datetime import datetime

slot_id_list = [1, 2, 3 , 6, 23]
slotbooking_obj = SlotBooking.objects.create(timing=datetime.now())

through_model = SlotBooking.slot.through

through_model.objects.bulk_create(map(lambda slot_id: through_model(slotbooking_id=slotbooking_obj.id, slot_id=slot_id), slot_id_list))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Answer (score 0):

If you have list of items (not ids), you can achieve it by using:

```
slot_booking = SlotBooking(token=value)
slot_booking.save()
slot_booking.slot.add(*list_of_slots)
```